# "is-active" class on all menu levels

Tags: 8, navigation

My main navigation menu is visually split as in the picture:

[image]

Level 1 is visualised in the upper-right corner, level 2 below.

`Technology` (like all the current items in level 2) is child of `About`.

In the screenshot, `Technology` has been assigned the class `is-active`. Is there a way to also assign it to `About`? In other words, I would like the entire active branch of the menu to be displayed as active.

Comment: If you do so it looks weird. The active link denotes the current page content. For example if the content is related to technology, you should not show active link for other menu items. That's my suggestion, if your requirements is such a way, try my answer below

Comment: I tend to agree with you, but indeed, those are the requirements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve that by using the [Menu Trail By Path](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_trail_by_path) module.

> Menu Trail By Path sets the active-trail on menu items according to
>   the current url.
>
> For example if you are at yoursite.com/blog/category1/article1 Menu
>   Items with these paths will get the active-trail class on them and
>   expand accordingly.
>
> blog blog/category1 blog/category1/article1
>
> **8.x-1.x branch**
>
> 8.x-1.x branch is completely rewritten. It should be compatible with any menu.

Comment: I found out later that in Drupal 8 you get the `active-trail` class on *menu-items* of all levels, also without this module. I didn't see it before because I was looking for the `is-active` class on the menu *link* instead.